# Recursively assigning positions to node in binary search tree

Tags: java, recursion, tree

Hello I'm looking for a way to recursively assign the positions of a tree to an int index so the value of the node at the position can be put into an array.

The desired tree positions are designated in level-order where the root position is 1 (i) and the left child of i is at position 2i and the right child is 2i + 1 - like a heap structure. Null children do not get a position assigned to them.

```
        1
       / \
      2   3
     /\   /\
    4  5 6  7
       ...

 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7. ...]
```

And the largest position in the tree should be the size of the array. The addition of nulls as "space" is desired for my output to test the node values.

```
private int largestPos
// first call: assignPositions(root, 1)
assignPositions(node cur, int pos) {
   parent = new node;
   if curpos > largestPos
      largestPos = curPos

   if cur == null
      parent.pos = pos
   else
     current.pos = pos

   parent = cur
   if cur.left != null
      pos = 2 * pos
      assignPositions(cur.left, pos)
   if cur.right != null
      pos = 2 * pos + 1
      assignPositions(cur.right, pos)
}
```

as I try to print out my array I get the first two values are assigned correctly, then then a large block of nulls without values (that are confirmed in the tree) are not in the tree.

I am looking to do this to figure out the least size of an array I would need after removals within the tree.

**Update for breadthfirstsearch array:**

```
public Key[] breadthFirstTraversal() {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Key[] keysFinal = new Key[largestPos];

    List<Key> queue = new List<Key>();
    List<Key> keysList = new List<Key>();
    List<Integer> positions = new List<Integer>();

    if (!isEmpty()) {
        Node tempNode = root;
        KeyValuePair<Key, Value> tempKey = null;

        queue.add(tempNode);

        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            queue.reset();
            tempKey = queue.remove();
            keysList.add(tempKey);

            tempNode = findKey(tempKey.getKey(), root);

            // adds keys in order on level in list
            if (tempNode.getLeftChild() != null) {
                queue = addAtEnd(queue, tempNode.getLeftChild());
            }
            if (tempNode.getRightChild() != null) {
                queue = addAtEnd(queue, tempNode.getRightChild()); 
            }
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < largestPos + 1; i++) {
            keysList.reset();
            tempKey = keysList.remove();
            tempNode = findKey(, root);
            if (tempNode.getPosition() == i) {
                keysFinal[i - 1] = tempKey;
            } else {
                keysFinal[i - 1] = null;
            }
        }
    }

    return keysFinal;
}
```

Comment: The normal recursive way of processing trees won't work here.  I think what you have to do is while you process level 1, keep a "to-do" list of level-2 nodes to process.  Then go through this list, and while processing it, keep a "to-do" list of level-3 nodes.  Then when you're done with level 2, go through the list of level 3 nodes, etc.  Or you can keep everything in one queue.  Look up "tree traversal" in Wikipedia and scroll down to "breadth-first search".

Comment: @ajb I added my current breadth first search.

Answer (score 0):

You're changing `pos` to work on the left sub-tree, but then want the original value to work on the right subtree.  So don't change `pos`, just put the expression you want in the call to `assignPositions`.

Then again, you keep creating new nodes for each one you visit, and I don't see any array, so there's more to the problem than just that.

Comment: The array comes in later where I traverse the tree again, look at the current node's position, then from the position the nodes value gets added to an array at index [position at node - 1]. The array is not a necessary part of this problem, as it is used as the outcome of the current issue above.

Comment: So what you're saying is add a say `leftPos` and `rightPos`variables then in the if statements  'if (left != null) { leftPos = 2 * pos; assignPositions(cur.left, leftPos;` and the same for right?

Comment: Or you could just put the expression in the call; for example, `assignPositions(cur.left, 2*pos)`